# How does recursion work here?(Below Code)

Tags: c, function, recursion

```
#include<stdio.h>
void func(int x)
{
   if (x==0)
      return;
   else
   {
      func(--x);   
      printf("%d\t",x);
   }
}
void main()
{
    int k=2;
    func(k);
}
```

**Output: `0 1`**

Why isn't the output `0 1 2`?

When the function is called for the first time, the value of `x` is equal to 2.
Then it should also get printed at the end. I am confused with this code.
Can someone help me out?

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: The line ` if(x==0) return;` could hardly be clearer. If `x` is `0` then don't do the rest of this function.

Comment: As the next exercise - swap the `printf` and `func` lines. Then go and read about *head recursion* versus *tail recursion*.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux  What I am asking is it should print 0 1 2 . I am emphasizing on 2 because it belongs to the last activation record and technically it should print 2 but it ain't doing so.

Comment: @SatyendraYadav You are printing after you decrement `i`. Try `func(i - 1)` instead.

Comment: Yeah I got it now. Thank you @FrançoisAndrieux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters it would be more correctly to declare the parameter as having type `unsigned int`. Otherwise decreasing the parameter with a negative value can result in a very long output sequence.

In each recursive call of the function the parameter at first decreased and after decreasing it prints the output.

```
func(--x);   
     ^^^^
printf("%d\t",x);
```

So if the function initially was called with the argument equal to `2` then it outputs value `1` because the argument was decreased.

Thus

```
func( 2 ) --> outputs 1
func( 1 ) --> outputs 0
func( 0 ) --> outputs nothing
```

Only the innermost function call outputs its value firstly.

If you want that the output would look like

```
0 1 2
```

then the function should be defined as it is shown in this demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>

void func( unsigned int x )
{
    if ( x ) func( x - 1 );   
    printf( "%u\t", x );
}

int main(void) 
{
    func( 2 );
    putchar( '\n' );
}
```

The function output is

```
0   1   2
```

The function differs from the original function is that the argument itself is not decreased in the function call. It keeps its value unchanged.

```
if ( x ) func( x - 1 );   
               ^^^^^^ the variable x itself is not changed
```

**If the recursive call occurs at the beginning of a method, it is called a head recursion. The method saves the state before jumping into the next recursive call.**

Answer (score 1):

`--x` decreases the value of x and you do that before printing; that's why the output is `0 1` and not `0 1 2`.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to swap the recursive call after the printf.

```
#include<stdio.h>
void func(int x){
if(x==0){printf("%d\t",x);
return;}
else{
     func(--x);   
     printf("%d\t",x+1);
    }
  }
int main(){
    int k=2;
    func(k);
}
```

Comment: How is it answering the question?

Comment: Please explain more.

Comment: If you printf first and then call you'll have the correct output

Comment: This also reverses the order of the output.

Comment: Just noticed, my bad i'll fix this now

Answer (score 0):

Here, first value of `x` is decrease and pushed onto the stack each time until x== 0 and then, the final result is accumulated in the exact reverse order of the initial recursive function call.